# this is matlab code for drawing circle by 6dof arm robot but i don't know how to limit the joint's angles

Tags: robotic-arm, inverse-kinematics, matlab, forward-kinematics

````
clear,clc

R=175;
H= 150;
N=5;
c=[200,200];
theta=linspace(0,2*pi,N);
x= R*cos(theta)+c(1);
z= R*sin(theta)+c(2);
y= ones(1,length(x))*H;
End=[x',y',z'];
% plot3(x,y,z)

L(1)= Link('d', 0 , 'a', 44.51, 'alpha', pi/2);
L(2)= Link('d', -68.41, 'a', 257.4, 'alpha', 0);
L(3)= Link('d', 0 , 'a', 0, 'alpha', -pi/2);
L(4)= Link('d', 331.5 , 'a', 0, 'alpha', pi/2);
L(5)= Link('d', 0 , 'a', 0, 'alpha', -pi/2);
L(6)= Link('d', 0 , 'a', 72, 'alpha', -pi/2);
Arm= SerialLink(L, 'name', 'Inmoov');
t =(0:1:N-1);
time = t';
a=1;

for i =1:N-1
xa1 = End(i,1) ; ya1 = End(i,2) ; za1 = End(i,3);
xf1 = End(i+1,1) ; yf1 = End(i+1,2) ; zf1 = End(i+1,3) ;

stylus=true;

T11 = SE3(xa1,ya1,za1)*SE3.Rz(90);         % initial end effector pose
T12 = SE3(xf1,yf1,zf1)*SE3.Rz(90);         % final end effector pose

Ts1 = T11.ctraj(T12,length(t));

q1 = Arm.ikine(Ts1, [0 0 0 0 0], 'mask', [1 1 1 1 1 1]);



p41=transl(T11);
p42=transl(T12);

xa1=[p41(1),p42(1)];
y1=[p41(2),p42(2)];
z1=[p41(3),p42(3)];

qs1 = Arm.ikine(T11, [0 0 0 0 0], 'mask', [1 1 1 1 1 1]);

% 0 < q1(1) < pi/2;
% q1(5)=0;

    
% Arm.plot(q1);
hold on 
if stylus==true
    plot3(xa1,y1,z1)
end
Arm.plot(q1);
A(a,:)=qs1;
 a=a+1;
end
A=[A;A(1,:)];
th1=A(:,1)*180/pi;
th2=A(:,2)*180/pi;
th3=A(:,3)*180/pi;
th4=A(:,4)*180/pi;
th5=A(:,5);
%  figure
%  plot(th1,time)

```
````

Comment: what is your specific question?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Mostafa Mahmoud, but I'm afraid that it is not clear what you are asking. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so it's a good idea to include details of what you want to achieve, what you tried, what you saw & what you expected to see. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works and work through the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) to edit your question to make it clearer.

Comment: I want to make a condition to limit the angles for the joins can anyone help